# How detect video content in url?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, twitter, tweetsharp

I stream tweets in my wp8 app, using `TweetSharp`. I want to detect the content in each tweet. With photos it's simple, using `TwitterStatus.Entities.Media` its a collection of images. Harder with video, links to videos are in `TwitterStatus.Entities.Urls` (such as `youtube.com` or `youtu.be`, etc) with simple links to another sites. Official android Twitter app detects content type and show an icon forech type(link, video, photo). I tried to get this info just from JSON, but in JSON videolinks also are in `urls`, not in `media`. But android app knows how to detect content, so it can be make.

In complete solution I need just a `enum` field `ContentType` in `MyTwitterMessage` with `Photo`, `Video`, `Link` or `Nothing`

Comment: Why don't just check, if Url contains any of known video service address?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek How many video services do you know? 5? 10? 20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of ways I could think of is

a) Just use known file extensions and check if the extension which type it is and return (assuming all URLs will provide a file extension).

b) Fire off a download using the URL but only retrieving the headers

```
 WebClient aClient = new WebClient();
 WebHeaderCollection collection = new WebHeaderCollection();
 collection[HttpRequestHeader.Range] = "bytes=0-0";
 aClient.Headers = collection; 
 aClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("URI GOES HERE"));
```

Then in the DownloadStringCompleted event parse the headers and retrieve content-type

```
 var aClient = (Webclient)sender;
 var responseHeaders = client.ResponseHeaders;
 var TypeOfContent = responseHeaders["Content-Type"];
```

You should then be able to determine the content from there, MIME types can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type#Type_video)

For b) You might also need to handle redirects, but that's another question.